# Remote MySQL connection from Godaddy

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to connect to a remote mySQL server from a Godaddy hosting account.

```
$con = mysqli_connect("xx.xx.xx.xx","username","pass","db_name",'3306');
```

I am using the above code, but keep getting the following error back:

**Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xx.xx.xx.xx' (110)**

From the error it seems that it's trying to connect on port 110, even though I have specified 3306 as the port in the PHP call.

Comment: 110 means "Connection timed out", not "port 110". [source](http://major.io/2007/08/09/mysql-error-codes/)

Comment: Try specifying the port without quotes perhaps? I would think that you don't need to even specify the port if you're using the default one.

Comment: did you allow remote access to databases on xx.xx.xx.xx godaddy's server?.  you must able both, firewall and mysql to receive remote conecctions

Comment: This is a mysql server not hosted with godaddy.  The website is hosted with godaddy, attempting to connect to a remote mysql server hosted outside of godaddy.

Answer (score 1):

If the script resides on the same machine as the mysql server then change the ip address to 'localhost' and since you're using the default port you can drop that as well.

If your script is attempting to connect to a machine outside of your localhost, you may need to allow the ip either via iptables or the remote mysql host within cpanel.

Comment: I did add the godaddy web server IP to my remote Mysql access section within the cpanel where the mysql server is hosted.